# Navigator MediaDevices getUserMedia "Permission denied"

Tags: spring-boot, google-chrome, webrtc, jhipster, getusermedia

i'm facing a issue with getUserMedia using this code, wanting to get UserMedia to show local camera.

```
navigator
.mediaDevices
.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
.then(stream => {
    console.log("success!")
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log("e: ", e);
});
```

When i'm on http://localhost(:9000) : got "**success!**"
but when i'm online whith https://mydomaine.com:443 got `e:  DOMException: Permission denied` and not prompt for camera settings
!

- My SSL certification seems to be cool : [Security overview from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XnMg.png)
- My website option for camera are fine (asking mode) : [Chrome settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd3Qd.png)

My chrome v. 81.0.4044.129 (64bit) and i'm on Windows 10.
Works on **Firefox** (desktop & mobile) and **Edge** !

NB: Tried this lines in chrome console on stackoverflow : works !

---

My app is running with Spring Boot (it's a Jhispter app) and when i test previous line on chrome console it doesn't work. I tried to run a test-app on a Tomcat server using same Keystore file, trying again and that's work. Maybe a issue with my Spring boot app ? 
This is my app.yml conf for SSL in my Spring boot app

```
server:
port: 443
ssl:
    key-store: classpath:config/tls/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: PKCS12
```

Is my fisrt issue here, plz let me know if i'm doing something wrong !

Comment: can you test port 443 on your server if its open?

Comment: Yes yes it is, my app run on port 443 ! Thx.

Comment: Click on Chrome's SSL lock (on the location bar). You may see a pulldown menu for your camera permissions. If so, try changing it to Allow or Ask.  Then go here chrome://settings/content/camera and see if you can reset anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster as a restrictive [feature policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) configured by default. No access to [camera or microphone is allowed](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/0630cdd1880524e46e353fdf9026b962a2a34603/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/SecurityConfiguration.java.ejs#L251). You should set the values according to your needs.

Comment: Oh dear, i missed this, changed it and works for me, thanks !
Do you have any idea why it works on Firefox and Edge?

Comment: Not sure but feature policies are quite new. Not sure if every browser supports them

Comment: @atomfrede - can you explain what exact change you have made, I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Right the feature policy disallows e.g. camera by setting none. Depending on your use case you can allow access to camera/microphone to * or self. For details on the possible values see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy